# Why is this integral not integrable?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

[image]

I got this on a Calc 2 test as an MCQ. I have no idea how to think about this

Comment: Do you know the possible answers to choose from?

Comment: -1,-3,-5, or none of them

Comment: The answer is none of them, I just don't know how

Comment: The integrand is positive on the interval, so the answer can't be negative.

Comment: couldn't the cos term be negative between values of 2 and 15?

Comment: Yes, but $3+\cos(x^2)$ is between $2$ and $4$.

Answer (score 1):

*Just written for your curiosity.*

If the expression was
$$I=k \int_a^be^x (x-1) \sqrt{x} \log \left(x^2\right)\,dx$$ we could have an analytical solution in terms of special functions since
$$\int e^x (x-1) \sqrt{x} \log \left(x^2\right)\,dx=-\frac{8}{25} x^{5/2} \,
   _2F_2\left(\frac{5}{2},\frac{5}{2};\frac{7}{2},\frac{7}{2};x\right)+\frac{8}{9}
   x^{3/2} \,
   _2F_2\left(\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};\frac{5}{2},\frac{5}{2};x\right)+\frac{1}{4}
   \left(5 \sqrt{\pi } \text{erfi}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)+2 e^x \sqrt{x} (2
   x-5)\right) \log \left(x^2\right)$$ where appear hypergeometric functions.

Nice, isn't it ?